# Why std::string{"const char ptr"} works?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, initialization-list, uniform-initialization

I can see that std::string has only one CTOR with `initializer_list`: `string (initializer_list<char> il);` So initializer list should work with chars, right? Why `std::string{"some_str"}` works, it gets `const char*`, right?

Comment: Probably because string literals are convertible to `std::string`.

Comment: It's all part of the [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) process. Read that reference if you want all the details.

Comment: You seem to think that list-initialization will only consider constructors that take a `std::initializer_list` for overload resolution, which isn't the case.

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_strin), `std::string` has many constructors, including some taking `const CharT*`. Are you saying that information is wrong?

Comment: @Walter OP means, it has only one initializer_list constructor, and wondered if / how this one is used to construct a string with `std::string{"some_str"}`.

Comment: I see you tagged C++11. Braced initialization got some improvements in C++14 . Did you mean to specifically ask about that old version of C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

n3337 13.3.1.7/1

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized
> (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
> constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
> the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable
> initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is
> performed again, where the candidate functions are all the
> constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
> elements of the initializer list.

`std::string` has many [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). One of them, that receives `const char*`.

So, firstly compiler will take `initializer_list` c-tor in overload-resolution, but it's not viable candidate, when `string` is constructed with `const char*`, then compiler will look at other constructors and choose the best one, that is

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

You can check it with just simple example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class String
{
public:
   String(const std::initializer_list<char>&) { std::cout << "init-list c-tor called" << std::endl; }
   String(const char*) { std::cout << "const char* c-tor called" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
   String s{"hello"};
}
```

[Live version](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OGpGFbGV30maokzG)